# No wlan0 on RPi 3 B v1.2

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, wireless-adapter

On the motherboard of my Pi is written 'Raspberry Pi 3 Model B v1.2'. I was under the impression that Raspberry Pi 3 had a built-in Wifi interface. I installed Raspbian using NOOBS and ran the `ifconfig` command. The only adapters that show are `eth0` and `lo`.

Does this version not come with a WiFi adapter or have I missed some required setup? My Bluetooth adapter is also not visible - when I click on the Bluetooth icon in the menu bar it says `No Bluetooth adapter found'.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Very probably you have insufficient power going to it. You need a better charger.

Comment: try if 'iwconfig' shows the adapter

Answer (score 2):

I've found that most of my chargers don't provide enough power to my PI3, even if the "under-voltage" icon doesn't show up. This causes the Wifi and Bluetooth to be disabled in an otherwise working system. An original Apple iPad charger did the trick.

Comment: Hi Mike, when I first tried to figure out what was wrong I came across several people saying that in forums so I ordered the official Pi PSU (5.1v, 2.5A), and still no luck!

Comment: We'll, a defective pi isn't common but also not unheard of... I suggest you send it back. It's a bummer but less than having something that "half works".

Comment: Just FYI and anyone else stumbling across this - the Pi was faulty (i.e. don't waste hours of your time as it should work out of the box...). I swapped my OS loaded SD card into a colleague's Pi, of the exact same model, and it worked perfectly without any extra steps.

Comment: @petehallw I've seen dire warnings that jostling the WiFi chip while installing the Pi in a case can kill WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

[How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) describes the setup methods.If these do not work you may have a faulty download, and I suggest you try again.

Did you check the checksum of the download?

As you have not indicated what you have possibly tried, no one can know.

Comment: I downloaded the OS twice and had no luck with the WiFi/Bluetooth adapters. I've not tried anything thus far, simply booted my Pi and checked for wlan0. Supposedly it should work out of the box with a new install of Raspbian but that's not been the case for me unfortunately..